# Getting input from the printer port in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, parallel-port

Is there a way to accept input through the parallel (printer) port in x86 assembly? My friend is designing a chip, that connects to the printer port, that has switches on it to poll for input. He wrote a program in VB but he wanted me to make a program in assembly since he had to use a timer.

Comment: please specify the operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read at the corresponding [memory addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_port#Port_addresses) (0x378-0x37f for LPT1). But be aware that this will require elevated privileges (root/kernel) depending on your operating system.

**Edit:** On modern operating systems this will not work at all due to security limitations. You cannot access the port directly from a userspace program, you have to use the corresponding kernel functions.